# Error pls-00403 oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_BCK_ANAG
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ANAGRAFICA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT ID ,
NOME ,
COGNOME ,
DATA ,
NUMERO_DI_TELEFONO ,
COMUNE   
INTO BCK_ANAG
FROM ANAGRAFICA;  
END;
```

Why does oracle give me back error

> PLS-00403:expression 'BCK_ANAG' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a
>   SELECT/FETCH statement

and how can i solve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to put five columns into a single value?

Comment: what is "BCK_ANAG"

Comment: You have also not declared a variable named `bck_anag`

Comment: BCK_ANAG is a table i have created beforehand with `create table bck_anag as (select * from anagrafica);`

Comment: `select into` populates a variable, not a table. You need something like `insert into bck_anag ... select ... from anagrafica`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_BCK_ANAG
   BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON ANAGRAFICA
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO BCK_ANAG (ID,
                         NOME,
                         COGNOME,
                         DATA,
                         NUMERO_DI_TELEFONO,
                         COMUNE)
      SELECT :NEW.ID,
             :NEW.NOME,
             :NEW.COGNOME,
             :NEW.DATA,
             :NEW.NUMERO_DI_TELEFONO,
             :NEW.COMUNE
        FROM DUAL;
END;
```

I would assume this is what you're trying to do.

Comment: where is the trigger though?